# MVC Lock and unlock session on one call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-5

There is a special behavior I would like to achieve in MVC 5.

I have an ajax call that start after page load that call a slow third party API.
The flow goes like this:

1. Controller receive the call.
2. Controller access some session ressources.
3. Controller call third party API.
4. Controller update session variables.
5. Controller answer request.

I can't return information to the client since it contains sensitive data so I can't make this in seperates calls to hold data on the client side and then call third party api on a stateless action because I would have to return results of the call to the client to afterwhile make session updates.

This is what I would like to acheive:

1. Controller receive the call.
2. Controller access some session ressources.
3. Unlock sessions to allow cocurent calls to access it.
4. Controller call third party API.
5. Lock session and update session variables.
6. Controller answer request.

Is it acheivable?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some try and error I found a solution but it's ugly.

What I did was to cache request parameter on the application cache with a guid for the request. Pass the guid to the client which will call a stateless controller that will call the slow third party API and will not hold other ajax call. Once it's done return the guid to the client that will do a third ajax call to apply the api result to session variables and then refresh html.

Not the best but work perfectly so far i'll do some changes to reuse the cached request.